# Google Mybusiness API getLocatiosn returns empty

Tags: php, api, rest, google-api, google-my-business-api

I got a verified location in google mybusiness but when i use the API, it returns an empty array `[]` I am using this endpoint. I am using laravel 6 and curl library for HTTP requests in this project.

`'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/117177930435384486747/locations'`

Here is my whole controller function

```
   public function getLocations(Request $request){
        $url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/'.$request->account_id.'/locations:batchGet';
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Bearer '.$request->bearer_token
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
     
        return response()->json(json_decode($result,true));
    }
```

What did I miss? I already got the account info by using this endpoint
`https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts` and it got me a response of

```
{
    "accounts": [
        {
            "name": "accounts/117177930435384486747",
            "accountName": "Michael koh",
            "type": "PERSONAL",
            "state": {
                "status": "UNVERIFIED",
                "vettedStatus": "NOT_VETTED"
            },
            "profilePhotoUrl": "//lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Jv5Xr7SXjuE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/QryQ_2-Mjqo/s132-mo/photo.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the response, it says not verified. But when i go to google mybusiness UI. I got this when i click manage location. Seems weird because it shows verified.

[image]

PS:

I tried getting the location by calling this endpoint `GET https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/{parent=accounts/*}/locations` but I got an empty array

Comment: Your screenshot shows that this specific location is verified. The error message appears to refer to your personal account `Michael koh` though?

Comment: yes. but even if i query the location name sir @CBroe i got an empty array. I am using the endpoint `GET https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/{parent=accounts/*}/locations`

Comment: Have you found a solution for that?